# How to delete data from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have these tables:

```
event     (evt_id, evt_code, reg_id)

magnitude (mag_id, evt_id, value)

trace     (trace_id, pt_id)

point     (pt_id, evt_id)
```

I want to delete all rows from all tables related to `evt_id=1139`.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 24):

If you have control over your schema, I would make the schema use [cascading deletes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-constraints.html).

From the article (the more pertinent portion translated for your example)

```
CREATE TABLE point
(
    pt_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    evt_id integer REFERENCES event ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

If you have cascades set up, then you can just delete from the main event table and all the other tables will be cleaned up automatically

Otherwise, you need to delete all of the references first, then you delete the main table. You should do this in one transaction to keep data consistent

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM trace WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 FROM point WHERE evt_id = 1139 AND trace.pt_id = point.pt_id);
DELETE FROM point where evt_id = 1139;
DELETE FROM magnitude where evt_id = 1139;
DELETE FROM event where evt_id = 1139;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: How would you handle the case where you need a subquery to get the `evt_id`? Is there a way to write the query such that you don't have to repeat the subquery `(SELECT evt_id FROM some_table WHERE some_field....)`?

Answer (score 15):

The only non-trivial element in your question are deletes from the table `trace`. I guess it is safe to assume `trace.pt_id` is referencing `point.pt_id`?

Either you define a [foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) and just forget about the table `trace` (as already [pointed out by @kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10145867/939860)) or you have to take care of depending rows manually.

Since PostgreSQL **9.1** you can use [**data-modifying CTEs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

```
BEGIN;

WITH x AS (
    DELETE FROM point WHERE evt_id = 1139
    RETURNING pt_id
    )
DELETE FROM trace
USING x
WHERE trace.pt_id = x.pt_id;

DELETE FROM magnitude WHERE evt_id = 1139;

DELETE FROM event WHERE evt_id = 1139;

COMMIT;
```

The [RETURNING clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html) of the `DELETE FROM point` returns all affected `pt_id` - those are in turn used to delete all corresponding rows from `trace`.

You did not mention whether **concurrency** is a problem in your case. If it is, and if you want to avoid possible results in the short time window in between deletes where rows for `evt_id = 1139` are present in one table while already deleted from another, wrap it all into a **transaction**.
If that is no concern to you, ignore `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.

To avoid **deadlocks** always use the same sequence of delete statements (in all concurrent transactions). This avoids situations where one transaction would start deleting in one table, the next in the other table and then each would wait for the other.

Answer (score 5):

If the rows you want to delete can be envisioned as a hierarchy, you could define FOREIGN KEY constraints for the relationships with the ON DELETE CASCADE clause.  Deleting the row at the top will then cascade down and delete them all.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

Answer (score -3):

I assume that the id's in the different tables correspond and are used for linking.
I also assume you want to delete all the trace points allthough they are only indirectly linked to evt_id

You can delete your records from all tables as follows:

```
DELETE event , magnitude, trace, point
FROM event left join magnitude on event.evt_id = magnitude.evt_id
   left join point on event.evt_id = point.evt_id
       left join trace on point.pt_id = trace.trace_id
where event_id=1139
```

Comment: This will only work in mysql, and the OP has re-tagged this question from mysql and postgresql to only postgresql

Answer (score -4):

```
$delete =  1139;
$query = "DELETE FROM event, magnitude, point WHERE evt_id = '$delete'";
mysql_query($query, $con);
$query = "DELETE FROM trace WHERE pt_id = '$delete'";
```

or just paste that statement into an .sql file and run it, or into your sql software query window, or place it in a .php file and run on the server.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't delete from multiple tables like that (but I could be wrong). However, at minimum `trace` does not have an evt_id column

Comment: The database is on the server. How do i run this query file?

Comment: Yes thats true trace doesnt have an evt_id column but has pt_id which is from the point table which has evt_id column..that is confusing !

Comment: @JustinPihony, I didn't know that either, but it looks like mysql does support that - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html

Comment: @user1202766 Ahhh, I did not notice the mySQL tag since the last tag was postgresql...which does not...please fix your tags :)

Comment: @user1202766 place the above function along with a db connect in a php file and run it on your server. also, google heidisql.

Comment: The fix is valid, however the OP has updated the tag to point that this is indeed postgresql and not mysql. So, this will not work